# Personalizar os valores do eixo x (abcissas) nas funções geom_smooth ou geom_ribbon do pacote ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Embora tenha já um pergunta semelhante a solução ali apresentada `scale_x_continuous` não me atendeu no meu problema.

Normalmente para isso eu usaria a função `factor` em `ggplot(data,aes(x=factor(TEMPO),y=media)` porém, como gostaria de usar a função `geom_smooth`, ou a função `geom_ribbon`, a mesma apresenta erro como mostrado na imagem 3.

Os valores que gostaria que fossem apresentados no **eixo x** correspondessem exatamente aos valores `(0, 21, 28, 35, 42, 56)`, e não `(0, 40)` como fica aparecendo no gráfico.

Base de dados:

```
pred<-structure(list(BLOCO = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), TEMPO = c(0L, 21L, 
28L, 35L, 42L, 56L), media = c(2.45833333333333, 5.04166666666667, 
6.25, 6.25, 7.125, 6.58333333333333), fit = c(1.71363636363637, 
4.71785714285714, 5.3530303030303, 5.80508658008658, 6.07402597402597, 
6.06255411255411), lwr = c(0.60162475497148, 3.92049437827316, 
4.56078873956403, 5.03472573973636, 5.31430598783235, 4.98323404726112
), upr = c(2.82564797230126, 5.51521990744113, 6.14527186649658, 
6.57544742043679, 6.8337459602196, 7.1418741778471)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Código da Imagem 1, a saída com eixo x (0, 40)

```
ggplot(pred,aes(x=TEMPO,y=media)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(stat="identity",aes(y=fit, x=TEMPO, colour = "sin"))+
  geom_ribbon(stat="identity",aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr, x=TEMPO, fill = "band"), alpha = 0.3)+
  scale_colour_manual("",values="blue")+
  scale_fill_manual("",values="grey12")
```

Imagem 1

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da Imagem 2, usando o indicado em uma pergunta similar a função `scale_x_continuous`

```
ticks <- floor(seq(1,6, length.out=6))

ggplot(pred,aes(x=TEMPO,y=media)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(stat="identity",aes(y=fit, x=TEMPO, colour = "sin"))+
  geom_ribbon(stat="identity",aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr, x=TEMPO, fill = "band"), alpha = 0.3)+
  scale_colour_manual("",values="blue")+
  scale_fill_manual("",values="grey12")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1, 6), breaks=ticks, labels=unique(pred$TEMPO))
```

Iamgem 2

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da Imagem 3, usando a função `factor`

```
ggplot(pred,aes(x=factor(TEMPO),y=media)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(stat="identity",aes(y=fit, x=TEMPO, colour = "sin"))+
  geom_ribbon(stat="identity",aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr, x=TEMPO, fill = "band"), alpha = 0.3)+
  scale_colour_manual("",values="blue")+
  scale_fill_manual("",values="grey12")
```

Iigura 3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu não entendi porque transformar `TEMPO`, que é uma variável contínua, em uma variável categórica através da função `factor`. Veja que ao deixar `TEMPO` como ela deve ser, eu consigo utilizar `scale_x_continuous` para criar os labels no eixo x como desejados:

```
ggplot(pred,aes(x=TEMPO,y=media)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(stat="identity",aes(y=fit, x=TEMPO, colour = "sin"))+
  geom_ribbon(stat="identity",aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr, x=TEMPO, fill = "band"), alpha = 0.3)+
  scale_colour_manual("",values="blue")+
  scale_fill_manual("",values="grey12") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 21, 28, 35, 42, 56),
                 labels=c(0, 21, 28, 35, 42, 56),
                 minor_breaks = NULL)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]